# Staggered Gridview ( Etsy ) with Volley Network Image View

Tags: android, json, android-volley, staggered-gridview

I would like to implement Etsy's Staggered Gridview.
Problem is, that i don't know how to combine Volley's NetworkImage View with this.
I get the Imageurl from a Json file, for that i'm using volley.

Here is my MainActivity.class

```
import com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView;


 public class NeuImKino extends ActionBarActivity {    
 private Toolbar toolbar;



// Log tag
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url
private static final String url =     "http://***json";

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
private static String Title = "title";
private static String movie = "movie";
private static StaggeredGridView mGridView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_neu_im_kino);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);

    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout), toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    mGridView = (StaggeredGridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    //listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();


    // JSON PARSING
    JsonObjectRequest movieReq = new JsonObjectRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();
                    parseJSONResponse(response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    }

    );

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().

            addToRequestQueue(movieReq);


    /**listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(NeuImKino.this, SingleItemView.class);

                                            intent.putExtra(Title, name);

                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    }

    ); **/
}


public void parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        if (response.has("movie")) {
            JSONArray arrayMovies = response.getJSONArray("movie");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayMovies.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentMovie = arrayMovies.getJSONObject(i);
                Movie movie = new Movie();

                String title = null;
                if (currentMovie.has("title")) {
                    title = currentMovie.getString("title");
                } else {
                    title = "NA";
                }

                String fsk;
                if (currentMovie.has("fsk")) {
                    fsk = currentMovie.getString("fsk");
                } else {
                    fsk = "NA";
                }
                String country = null;
                if (currentMovie.has("country")) {
                    country = currentMovie.getString("country");
                } else {
                    country = "NA";
                }


                String start = null;
                if (currentMovie.has("start")) {
                    start = currentMovie.getString("start");
                } else {
                    start = "NA";
                }

                String longdesc = null;
                if (currentMovie.has("longdesc")) {
                    longdesc = currentMovie.getString("longdesc");
                } else {
                    longdesc = "NA";
                }

                String imgname = null;
                if (currentMovie.has("imgname")) {
                    imgname = currentMovie.getString("imgname");
                } else {
                    imgname = null;
                }
                movie.setTitle(title);
                movie.setFsk(fsk);
                movie.setStart(start);
                movie.setCountry(country);
                movie.setLongDesc(longdesc);
                movie.setImgName(imgname);
                movieList.add(movie);


            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

My CustomListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static String CONFIG_URL = "http://****";
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Movie> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();



// Constructor
public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItem) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

// Create each list view row
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        // Layout Inflater to call external xml layout
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        // Inflate list_row_neuimkino file for each row
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_neuimkino, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


    DynamicHeightImageView poster = (DynamicHeightImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    //TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    //TextView fsk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fsk);
    //TextView start = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.start);


    // getting movie data for the row from Model object
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
 // Set Model Values in Holder Items
    // thumbnail image

    //poster.setImageUrl(CONFIG_URL+m.getImgName()+"_w300.jpg", imageLoader);


    // title
   // title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // fsk
    //fsk.setText("FSK: " + m.getFsk());

    // Startdatum
    //start.setText("Beginnt: " +m.getStart());


    return convertView;
}

}
```

And finally my layoutfile for one row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.etsy.android.grid.util.DynamicHeightImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go through from this URL http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/
try to understand it that how he has parsed the URL for images.....
I am a newbie but I followed and made it.

Thanks !!